# Custom view button click on AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView Adapter class in which every view holder has an onclick listener. When the user clicks on the view holder, I want a dialog box to be shown with a custom view.

My *dialog_custom.xml* is like this:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    … >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        … >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            … />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        … />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the user clicks the Button(*btn_ok*), I want to return the name entered in *txt_name* to the ViewHolder class and display it in a TextView. How many I supposed to do this?

My *MyAdapter.kt*:-

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    …
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) holder.addMessage()
        else holder.bind(list[position])
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setView(R.layout.dialog_custom)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .create().show()
            }
        }
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm.I don't get your question exactly. Your view holder has access to `txt_name` and you can easily read inputted string. I don't get what is your problem exactly.

Comment: txt_name and btn_ok are in the dialog box which appears when user clicks the view holder. My question is that how do I retrieve the name from the alert dialog box?

Comment: Aha got it. I have done this, but in java. I post a sample code in java for you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could use Kotlins [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html). Use a wrapper class the show your AlertDialog and post the value of the text field.

```
class MyInputDialog(private val context){
    public var input = MutableLiveData("")

    public fun showDialog(){
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).run{
            setView(R.layout.dialog_custom)
            show()
        }
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Confirm") { _, _ -> Unit
            input.postValue(dialog.your_text_input.text.toString())
        }
   }
}
```

Then in your Viewholder you call:

```
InputDialog(context).apply{
     showDialog()
     input.observe(context, Observer { 
         if(it != ""){
             //Do whatever you want with it
         }
     }
}
```

Note that this code isn't tested, but it should work something like this.

Comment: input.observe method takes two parameters - LifecycleOwner object and Observer Interface. You have passed the context object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do what you need to do:

```
public class NumberDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private final static String DIALOG_TITLE_PARAM = "DIALOG_TITLE_PARAM";
    private final static String DIALOG_PARAM_PARAM = "DIALOG_PARAM_PARAM";


    private OnNumberDialogClickListener mCallback = null;
    private EditText mEdit = null;
    private int mParam = 0;

    public interface OnNumberDialogClickListener {
        void onNumberDialogPositiveClick(int req, int val);
    }

    public static NumberDialog newInstance(String title, int req) {
        NumberDialog dialog = new NumberDialog();

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString(DIALOG_TITLE_PARAM, title);
        params.putInt(DIALOG_PARAM_PARAM, req);
        dialog.setArguments(params);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            Fragment frag = getTargetFragment();
            if (frag != null) {
                mCallback = (OnNumberDialogClickListener)frag;
            } else {
                mCallback = (OnNumberDialogClickListener)context;
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                    " must implement OnNumberDialogClickListener");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString(DIALOG_TITLE_PARAM);
        mParam = getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_PARAM_PARAM);

        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_number, null, false);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        builder.setTitle(title).
                setView(layout).
                setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).
                setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

        mEdit = layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_number_edit);

        final AlertDialog alert_dialog = builder.create();

        alert_dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                alert_dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mEdit != null) {
                            String valStr = mEdit.getText().toString();

                            int val;

                            try {
                                val = Integer.parseInt(valStr);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                return;
                            }

                            mCallback.onNumberDialogPositiveClick(mParam, val);
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        alert_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        return alert_dialog;
    }
}
```

This is a sample class for a number dialog which validates input to be a number and closes the alert dialog only if it is a number. If number is valid, it calls back to main class using `onNumberDialogPositiveClick()`.

This code shows you how to:

1. Use a callback from your alert dialog to run a code on your class class.
2. How to validate your data in your alert dialog before closing it.
3. Use custom layout for your alert dialog.

Just create a instance of `NumberDialog` and implement `onNumberDialogPositiveClick()` to see how it works. This gives you the general idea of how your code should change.